# How to calculate in R with variables

Tags: r

I'm a R newbie.

is there a way i can calculate

```
(x+x^2+x^3)^2
```

in R?

so i will get the result:

```
x^6+2 x^5+3 x^4+2 x^3+x^2
```

I get an Error: object 'x' not found.

Thanks!

Comment: you might want to look up:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/symbolic-computation-in-r

Answer (score 3):

R isn't well suited for this. Some interface packages to languages and libraries that are better at this do exist, such as [rSymPy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rSymPy/index.html), which allows you to access the SymPy Python library for symbolic mathematics (you'll need to install both).  In a similar vein, [Ryacas](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/index.html) links to the [yacas](http://www.yacas.org/) algebra system.

Those interfaces are useful if you need symbolic manipulation as part of an R workflow. Otherwise, consider using the original tools. The ones above are open source and freely available, while other free use alternatives also exist, such as the  proprietary web based [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) (for limited use).

Comment: "*R isn't well suited for this*"? Do you have anything to back that statement?

Comment: I agree with @MichaelVeale that R is not a well suited language for symbolic calculations. Owing to sympy and numpy Python would be, for instance, a better choice. There is absolutely no need to back up this statement, as pure logic implies: one can only backup a positive statement by presenting a viable solution, but not provide the proof of an absence. I'd like to add that [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) is a good and freely available standalone program for such purposes.

Comment: @RHertel So you are saying that external packages in Python is OK, but not external packages in R?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, I think that mimicking Python with rSymPy hardly makes sense. It is much more appropriate to work directly with Python in such cases. The syntax is simpler.

Comment: As far as I know, R has no well-developed native CAS packages that aren't just interfaces to other languages (which I've outlined). Why they don't exist is a different question, which I expect is as much a result of coalescing of people to projects than any restrictions in R compared to, say, Python. I'd also note that R can perform simple differentiation using `expression` and `deriv`

Comment: The documentation for `deriv` also demonstrates the limited ability of the internal `simplify()` function https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/deriv.html